# Descriptor __get__ from method

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand what  the `__get__` descriptor is doing in code below.
I have wrote all tutorial about `__get__`, still can't get what's happening here.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, socket, address=None):
      self.sock = socket
      self.address = address
      self.verbose = True

class B():
    def __init__(self):
      self.clients = []
      self.slaves = []
      self.pending_tasks = []
      self.running_tasks = {}
      self.finished_tasks = {}


class C(B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(C, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def handle_new_connection(self, socket, address):
        link = A(socket, address)

    def bind(self, host, port):
        handle = self.handle_new_connection.__get__(self, C)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = C()
    m.bind('0.0.0.0', 6666)
```

What the `__get__` is doing in bind method?

Comment: It is *entirely redundant*, as `self.handle_new_connection` does the binding *already*.

Comment: handle variable is sending to gevent.server.StreamServer. I suppose that __get__ in handle returns sock and address from NetLink? Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__get__` call is redundant and useless. The method is *already bound*, all the `__get__` call does is bind it again:

```
>>> m = C()
>>> m
<__main__.C object at 0x10b2cbeb8>
>>> m.handle_new_connection
<bound method C.handle_new_connection of <__main__.C object at 0x10b2cbeb8>>
>>> m.handle_new_connection.__get__(m, C)
<bound method C.handle_new_connection of <__main__.C object at 0x10b2cbeb8>>
```

Note how the `__get__` method call on the already bound method object returned the bound method object itself; nothing changed here.

The only reason I can think of to jump through this hoop (other than not understanding that a Python method lookup already invoked the function descriptor), is to be able to call the method as a class method (by passing in an explicit first argument that is not an instance but a class):

```
>>> C.handle_new_connection
<function C.handle_new_connection at 0x10b5e32f0>
>>> C.handle_new_connection.__get__(C, C)
<bound method type.handle_new_connection of <class '__main__.C'>>
>>> C.bind(C, '0.0.0.0', 6666)
```

because in that case `self.handle_new_connection` resolves into the original unbound function.

Comment: The code is still poorly written.  It would make more sense to just declare `handle_new_connection` as a `@classmethod` (or even a `@staticmethod`) in the first place.

Comment: @Kevin: absolutely. I'm leaning towards the "doesn't understand what they are doing" explanation here.